# Run training verbosely to check status if command

Tags: tensorflow

I have been running this command: `bazel run -c opt tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate -- --data_dir /Users/Username/data/ --train_dir /Users/User/train/  --en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000 --size 256 --num_layers 2 --steps_per_checkpoint=50`

for about 10 hours, and still no output. Is there a way to run the command in a verbose mode?

Answer (score 1):

The RNN translation example does not have a specific "verbose" flag, but all of its modes produce output on stdout. The default mode is to train a model, which runs indefinitely, producing output (and a model checkpoint) every `--steps_per_checkpoint=N` steps.

It is possible that Bazel is buffering standard output from the process, so you aren't able to see progress being made. Try running the built binary instead:

```
$ bazel build tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate -c opt
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate --data_dir /Users/Username/data/ --train_dir /Users/User/train/  --en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000 --size 256 --num_layers 2 --steps_per_checkpoint=50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the flags for this bazel command with `bazel help`, which will give you something [like this](http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html). I have not run the command, but looking through that page I see the following section **Verbosity options: options that control what Bazel prints**, which has what you want:

- `--explain logfile`
- `--verbose_explanations`
- `--profile file`
- `--[no]show_progress`
- `--show_result n`

All sounds close to what you want. Read docs for details.